# The set of points in 2-space that satisfy a condition

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let **u**= $\langle X,Y \rangle$ and **v**= $\langle X_1,Y_1 \rangle$. Describe the set of points $(X,Y)$ in 2-space that satisfy the stated conditions:

$(a)$ ||**u** - **v**||$=1$

$(b)$ ||**u** - **v**||$≤1$

$(c)$ ||**u** - **v**||$>1$

I don't know how to answer these questions. I see that the answer to $(a)$ would be two concentric circles where the difference between their respective radii would be 1, but I don't know how to answer the question. I am even more lost on $(b)$ and $(c)$. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure if you meant for subscripts for **v**? If my edits are incorrect with respect to what you intended, feel free to undo them.  For angle brackets use "\langle X, Y \rangle" (enclosed in dollar signs, of course).  Your coordinates inside "< >" were rendered invisible, for some reason. Angle brackets per code: $\langle X, Y \rangle$ vs. $<X, Y>$...see the difference?

Comment: @Theo: Hello!!  Good suggestion: using backticks ... Sometimes I think they're overused, but in cases like this, when pointing out (La)TeX)-issues, etc., they're particularly helpful.  Thanks!

Comment: I assume $X_1$, $Y_1$ are fixed numbers. Then (a) is tthe circle with center $(X_1,Y_1)$, radius $1$.  (b) is same circle plus its interior. (c) is all points outside the same circle. Can't say much more, hard to type in TeX without feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is not entirely clear. I will take it to mean, $\bf v$ is given, describe the set of $\bf u$ such that $\|{\bf u}-{\bf v}\|=1$, etc. If my interpretation is incorrect, perhaps OP will clarify and we can make some progress.

So anyway the set of $\bf u$ such that $\|{\bf u}-{\bf v}\|=1$ is a circle of radius 1, centered at $\bf v$. In terms of the $x$, $y$ variables, it's the set of $(x,y)$ such that $(x-x_1)^2+(y-y_1)^2=1$.

Now can you see what to do with the other two parts of the question?

Comment: It's not my fault that the question is worded in a way that makes it hard to understand; that's why I asked it in the first place. And no, I still don't understand what to do with the other two parts of the question.

Comment: I don't blame you for the unclear wording. Do you understand why the set of $\bf u$ such that $\|{\bf u}-{\bf v}\|=1$ is a circle centered at $\bf v$? Do you understand why that leads to the equation $(x-x_1)^2+(y-y_1)^2=1$? Did the comment from user6312 do anything for you?